# Difference between RSA_sign and EVP_DigestSignX()

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I have 2 codes, both are supposed to sign a SHA256 hash string and both use openssl library from C++ with a private key. However, I do not understand the difference between them. I did not write any of these codes.

The first one uses EVP_DigestSign functions.

```
bool RSASign( RSA* rsa,
              const unsigned char* Msg,
              size_t MsgLen,
              unsigned char** EncMsg,
              size_t* MsgLenEnc) {
  EVP_MD_CTX* m_RSASignCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
  EVP_PKEY* priKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
  EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(priKey, rsa);
  if (EVP_DigestSignInit(m_RSASignCtx,NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL,priKey)<=0) {
      return false;
  }
  if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) {
      return false;
  }
  if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, NULL, MsgLenEnc) <=0) {
      return false;
  }
  *EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*MsgLenEnc);
  if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, MsgLenEnc) <= 0) {
      return false;
  }
  EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(m_RSASignCtx);
  return true;
}
char* signMessage(std::string privateKey, std::string plainText) {
  RSA* privateRSA = createPrivateRSA(privateKey); 
  unsigned char* encMessage;
  char* base64Text;
  size_t encMessageLength;
  RSASign(privateRSA, (unsigned char*) plainText.c_str(), plainText.length(), &encMessage, &encMessageLength);
  Base64Encode(encMessage, encMessageLength, &base64Text);
  free(encMessage);
  return base64Text;
}
```

The second one is very different, it doesn't use any of the EVP_.. functions.

```
RSA * createRSA(unsigned char * key,int public_private)
{
    RSA *rsa= RSA_new(); //NULL;
    if (rsa == NULL)
    {
        LOGF_WARN("Failed to create RSA");
        return 0;
    }
    BIO *keybio ;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio==NULL)
    {
        LOGF_TRACE( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return 0;
    }
    if(public_private)
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }

    return rsa;
}
int private_sign(const unsigned char * data, int data_len, unsigned char * key,
    unsigned char *sigret, unsigned int * siglen){
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,0);
    if (rsa == NULL || !rsa) 
    {
        LOGF_TRACE("Failed to create RSA");
        printLastError("SELLADO RSA-");
        return 0;
    }
    printLastError("SELLADO RSA-");
    int result =  RSA_sign(NID_sha256, data, data_len,sigret, siglen, rsa);

    return result;
}
```

I found these codes because I want to sign a SHA256 hash that I previously make on my program. But I'm not very experienced with cryptography so I'm struggling to understand the difference between these two codes, I've read that EVP functions are high level, does this mean that the other ones are low level?

Hope you can help me out here, thanks in advance...and if you need anything else let me know.

Source:
http://hayageek.com/rsa-encryption-decryption-openssl-c/
https://gist.github.com/irbull/08339ddcd5686f509e9826964b17bb59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical sign process consists of
1) digest(`message`) => `md`
2) do_something_using_private_key(`md`) => `signature`

The EVP_DigestSignXXXs do these two steps for you, and RSA_sign do step 2 only, you need to do step 1 yourself, using [EVP_DigestXXXs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/EVP_DigestInit.html), [SHA256_XXX](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SHA256_Init.html), ...

For example:

```c
unsigned char md[64];
SHA256(data, datalen, md);
RSA_sign(rsakey, md, mdlen, sig, &siglen);
```

The function `private_sign`'s parameters `data`, `data_len` are somewhat of confusing. A message digest (`md`) should be passed in actually.

Comment: Very useful. I will stay with the EVP one.